# Cocoa Touch - How to cache a CGImageRef or UIImage (not using imageNamed:)?

Tags: cocoa-touch, caching, uikit, uiimage, cgimage

I have a lot of images in my app so I decided to do some loading in a background thread, and since UIKit isn't thread-safe, I filled arrays with CGImageRefs. However, they are not cached and I need to be able to access them fast so my question is:

How to cache CGImageRef, or cache the UIImage derived from it later on in the main thread?

Comment: If you're asking about UIImage, then you're asking about Cocoa Touch, not Cocoa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UIImageView+Cached code found [here](http://www.roathe.com/2009/12/how-to-background-load-and-cache-uiimageviews-images/) implements a simple cache of UIImages combined with background loading in a thread.

I use this in my own projects.  It works well.  I recommend it.  It should be easily adaptable to do what you want and a quick look says that pulling out the caching bits should be easy.